# Blog site that will show blog posts from different blog sites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2013 i want to show blog posts from different blog sites (under same site collection) on my blog site. please suggest how can i achieve it using OOTB features.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be to use a Content By Search Webpart (CSWP) to find all your blogs. The CSWP is able to search over all your sitecollections, so it will also find all blogs within a sitecollection even if there posted on different blog sites.

You can add the CSWP to the `default.aspx` of your blog site. There a plenty of blogpost on internet which describe how to use the Content By Search Webpart. For eamxple:

- https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Configure-a-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a

The most complicated in there is setting the correct query. The query you could use is `ContentTypeId:0x0110* Path:{SiteCollection.URL}`. The `ContentTypeId:0x0110*` is set to the ID of the Blog Content Type so only items of that specific Content Type will show. `Path:{SiteCollection.URL}` means we only want results from the current sitecollection.

Afther the query is set your results might look like this:

[image]

These are three blogpost which come from diffrent subsites of the same sitecollection on my development machine. The results might not look like you want them too. You can edit the way the results of the CSWP look by using display templates. The following link from microsoft explains how to create a custom display template for your search results.

Comment: I could not post my second link in the answer:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj945138.aspx